# Is this possible using perl?

Tags: perl, user-interface

As soon as I login to my system (basically linux) I get the below screen 
[image]

Now I use arrow button and goto "GET_TESTROOT" and then press enter and takes me to this screen

![second image][2]

Here I confirm and say "yes" and it will bring me to another screen 
[image]

Now I need to get the "serial number" and "testroot ID" into a variable.

Is this even possivble in perl ?

Comment: One of your slides left your IP address in the clear for the world to see.

Comment: +1 for being a lazy hacker! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these "screens" appear immediately after login (ie. executed from .profile or set directly as user shell) then the short answer is no!

The long answer is, **of cause you can**. You would have to create an [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script which connects to the server, sends some phony key presses and parses the output (which looks like some variant of [curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) to me). When that script is done, you can invoke it from Perl and extract the wanted values.

You can get most of the tools you need for this from [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

Comment: The first screen appear as soon as you login with username and password.. and then you can navigate to the second and thrid screen. This is basically the user shell. The user can only work on this using mouse or keyboard